# mysql join query returns data repeatedly

Tags: c#, mysql

i want to retrieve data from mysql database (using join query) in c# windows form but it gives me the data repeatedly 100 times.
This is my code. please help.

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex < 0 || comboBox2.SelectedIndex < 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please select the Class and group");
            }
            else
            {
                table = dbOperation.select("student.admission_no, student.studid, student.name from student inner join " +
                                            "studentinclass on studentinclass.studentid = student.studid inner join " +
                                            "class on studentinclass.classid = " + comboBox1.SelectedValue + " inner join " +
                                            "`group` on studentinclass.groupid = " + comboBox2.SelectedValue + " inner join " +
                                            "section on studentinclass.sid = " + comboBox3.SelectedValue);
                listView1.Items.Clear();

                foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
                {
                    listView1.Items.Add(row[0].ToString());
                    listView1.Items[listView1.Items.Count - 1].SubItems.Add(row[1].ToString());
                    listView1.Items[listView1.Items.Count - 1].SubItems.Add(row[2].ToString());
                    listView1.Items[listView1.Items.Count - 1].SubItems.Add("P");
                }
            }
        }
```

this is the output

[image]

Comment: And what is the output you are expecting? BTW adding a 'DISTINCT' after the Select keyword will help you eliminate all the repeating rows.

Comment: What type is `dbOperation`?

Comment: it is the object of the class in which the databse is connected.

Comment: simply i don't want the repetition Neel.

Answer (score 0):

Is student ID the primary key in both the tables?

Comment: Does student ID uniquely identify each record in both tables?

Answer (score 0):

You are going to need a subquery to compare

The full select statement wants to be

```
"student.admission_no, student.studid, student.name from student " +
"where student.studid in ( select studentinclass.studentid from studentinclass " +
"inner join class on studentinclass.classid = " + comboBox1.SelectedValue + " " +
"inner join `group` on studentinclass.groupid = " + comboBox2.SelectedValue + " " +
"inner join section on studentinclass.sid = " + comboBox3.SelectedValue +")"
```